# My Menu Will Only Semi Translate

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n, features

I have created a menu on my site and have used features to export it. The first 2 menu items are translating to different languages but the third is not.

The third word is Contact. I have gone to `/admin/config/regional/translate/translate` and searched for Contact. I get the following.

[image]

At the bottom of my features it has

```
  // Translatables
  // Included for use with string extractors like potx.
  t('Contact');
```

So we can see that is there OK.
When looking at my menu at `/admin/structure/menu/manage/menu-example` it is all in English. If I go to `/fr/admin/structure/menu/manage/menu-example` Contact remains in English and the other words change.

Contact is a mailto:link if that makes any difference.

```
  $menu_links['menu-teleplan_contact:mailto:a@a.com'] = array(
    'menu_name' => 'menu-example',
    'link_path' => 'mailto:a@a.com',
    'router_path' => '',
    'link_title' => 'Contact',
    'options' => array(
      'attributes' => array(
        'title' => '',
      ),
      'identifier' => 'menu-example_contact:mailto:a@a.com',
    ),
    'module' => 'menu',
    'hidden' => 0,
    'external' => 1,
    'has_children' => 0,
    'expanded' => 0,
    'weight' => -48,
    'customized' => 1,
  );
```

Why is the word in my menu not translating?

Comment: Are you using the i18n menu submodule to translate the menu?  If so, which of the four options have you selected for translation?

Comment: @PatrickKenny no I am not using the sub module. I have enabled it but not sure what to do next

Answer (score 3):

I think you will find there is a conflict somewhere that is preventing the specific word (as it is a link) from being translated, and this submodule should overcome the conflict. I would utilise the "Menu Translation" submodule as it will specifically achieve what you are attempting above, and hopefully make it simpler! I would use the Translate and Localize Menus option (a detailed guide of how to do that is [here](https://drupal.org/node/1113982))

If you are still stuck, and are using SuperFish for your menus (even though this is supported in i18n), there is a work around [here](https://drupal.org/node/1792462) and this may overcome the problem also.

Lastly, just in case, ensure you have this [update](https://drupal.org/node/2070589), the most recent version, installed also.

Comment: Ah, typo, I meant to put the link for 1.10. Thank you for pointing that out, I've fixed it now.

Comment: This seems to work. Just need to try and find a way to automate it in code...

Comment: Did you need to use the SuperFish work around? I will try and help you solve it programmatically and update my answer.